# Any further documentation needed to travel to the USA for the first time, with a previously issued visa B1/B2

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I had applied for a US B1/B2 visa last year to attend a conference. Since the visa process took very long I could not attend that particular conference. However, the visa was issued with a 1 year validity. There is another conference coming up soon within the time frame that my previous visa is still valid. Can I travel with the same visa? Is there any other documentation required ? (I am specifically asking because citizens of some countries that do not need a visa to travel to USA for toursim/conference etc), still need to fill an online form. Is there such a requirement for me in this case ?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered several times here, I can't seem to find the link. Simple answer is Yes you can and No you do not need to fill any form. If you want to carry any documents, it should be the supporting documents you typically use when applying for a visa.

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship?

Answer (score 2):

Visa is not something that get guarantee to enter in a country. So also in case you went in the first conference, it is a lot better to have documentations.

In your case, you have a valid visa, but it was issued for a specific reason, and you gave then specific documents. So take with you (carry on luggage) similar documents, e.g. conference invitation, program, hotel booking, etc.

If you have similar documents, it should not be a problem: they will had issued the visa also with new documents.

I cannot tell you about financial situation or family connection. If you think that before you were at limit of acceptability, you may need to bring new documents [mainly if you were jobless, and now after one year they could have some doubts]

The problems arise if you do not have similar document, or if the reason of the travel is different. These cases are more difficult, and they may requires a new visa (or you should bring convincing documents).

Last point. The ESTA is only for people using Visa Waiver Program (VWP) [it is not just being citizen of a country, it depends also on the purposes]. If you have a valid visa, the visa data is used, and you do not need ESTA.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will keep all of the documents that were submitted at the time of the Visa  application last time in addition to all the documents that are related to this upcoming conference.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are a Chinese national, you don't need to do anything. Chinese nationals with 10-year B1/B2 visas must register for EVUS before boarding to fly to the US; this EVUS lasts 2 years and needs to be renewed if you travel to the US after that.